# Using netbeans as IDE for Python

Tags: python, netbeans, netbeans6.8

I am about to embark on learning Python (largely for the purposes of using it as scripting glue between my applications).

I use Netbeans (6.8) on Linux for both my C++ and PHP development work. Ideally, I would like to use the same IDE for Python - and there is a Python plugin for Netbeans (admittedly, its still in Beta).

Does anyone have any experience using Python with Netbeans?

Shall I use Netbeans (for the reasons stated above - i.e. already familiar environment), or is there a [*GOOD*] reason why I should use a different IDE?

Comment: if you are learning python, I'd also recommend installing either ipython (http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) or bpython (http://bpython-interpreter.org/), which are both outstanding alternative interpreters that you can use for experimentation.  Either of them make a great compliment to ${yourEditorOfChoice}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I've not been using it for long, I was in the same situation as yourself and just decided to bite the bullet. I haven't had any issues with it so far and found he most important thing to be that you are using an environment that you are both familiar and comfortable with. Any quirks you find along the way are probably more than made up for by the shallow learning curve given by not having to get used to an entirely new IDE.

That said however, if you are only just picking the language up I can't recommend the "official" command interface, IDLE, enough as it just let's you get into the guts of the language giving instant feedback etc.

Additionally, the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) has a comprehensive list of Python IDE's if you find that the Python plugin for Netbeans just doesn't work for you.

Comment: I assume you are suggesting Netbeans then?

Comment: @morpheous: Yeah I can't see any reason not to if you already have experience with it :)